# Positioning in javax swing with gridbaglayout

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I've been self teaching myself swing for a few days for a project and right now I'm trying to figure out how to position components with a grid bag layout. I got most of it except a few small issues. If anyone could help, it would be very appreciated. I've tried this so many different ways D:

```
    ...
    titlePanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    titlePanel.setBackground(BLUE);

    header = new JLabel ("Gradebook");
    header.setLocation(200,400);
    header.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 50));
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 0;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    titlePanel.add(header,gbc);

    date = new Date();
    currentDate = new JLabel (fmt.format(date));
    currentDate.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
    ActionListener updateTime = new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            date = new Date();
            currentDate.setText(fmt.format(date));
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer (1000, updateTime);
    timer.start();
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 1;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    titlePanel.add(currentDate, gbc);

    JLabel userName = new JLabel ("Username:  ");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    titlePanel.add(userName, gbc);

    JTextField username = new JTextField (10);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 2;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    titlePanel.add(username, gbc);

    JLabel password = new JLabel ("Password:  ");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
    titlePanel.add(password, gbc);

    JPasswordField Password = new JPasswordField (10);
    gbc.gridx = 1;
    gbc.gridy = 3;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    titlePanel.add(Password, gbc);
    JButton login = new JButton ("Login");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 4;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    titlePanel.add(login, gbc);

    JButton newAccount = new JButton ("Create New Account");
    gbc.gridx = 0;
    gbc.gridy = 5;
    gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
    titlePanel.add(newAccount, gbc);
    mainFrame.add(titlePanel);
```

So when I run the code for the login screen, it comes up with this
[image]

I need a way to center the username and password so they match up with everything else and also add some blank vertical space between the 2 buttons at the bottom. Sorry if this is a dumb question :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your username/password contains two components in two different columns. So if you want all the components centered you have two options:

1. Create a separate panel for each of the label/text field components. Then you can add the panel as a single component which means it will be placed in the first column with all the other components.
2. Have all the other component "span" two columns. So now they will take up the same width as the label/text field components. In this case you will need to specify the `gridWidth` constraint.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information on the various constraints used by GridBagLayout.

> also add some blank vertical space between the 2 buttons at the bottom

Again, look at the constraints. You could use the `insets` constraint.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH

Comment: @bobbybobbins, forgot the tutorial link. See the tutorial for the suggest constraint. You may also find other constraints for future problems.